# moving Forward with constant rotation unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
void Update () {

    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    Vector3 velocity = new Vector3 ( 0  ,-maxspeed * Time.deltaTime  ,0);
    pos += transform.rotation * velocity;
    transform.position = pos;
    gameObject.transform.rotation = new Quaternion (0, 0, 1, 0);


}
```

This is my script for moving meteorites forward(top to bottom). but i want that my meteorites should rotate around its center. i added one simle line

i.e.

`gameObject.transform.rotation = new Quaternion (0, 0, 1, 0);`

but it is not working properly. it is rotating meteorites in arc not around its own center.

I have searched on internet about rotating objects around its center but i didnt get any proper guidance.

Comment: Why are you adding rotation to the position?

Comment: Maybe look into to [Torque](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) if it has a rigidbody.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
meteoritesRotationSpeed = 10.0f;
gameObject.transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward * meteoritesRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Instead of this:

```
gameObject.transform.rotation = new Quaternion (0, 0, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to rotate using `Quaternion`s you have to multiply them, hence `transform.rotation *= myQuaternion;` but to simply rotate your meteorite forward, you must rotate it on the `Vector3.right` axis, the other answer came close, but it will actually rotate on the wrong axis and wont pitch forward, as you asked.

```
float speed = 5f;
meteorite.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```